# Has anyone used Alien Skin Bokeh?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, digital, bokeh

I was wondering if anyone has had experience with using the Alien Skin Bokeh application. Is it worthwhile, or it gimmicky? Thanks!

Comment: why not download the trial and play for yourself? Also, OnOne software does Focal Point - http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/focalpoint/ which is similiar

Answer (score 6):

I've played around with it, but elected not to buy it. 
I was fairly impressed with the results, when it worked, but found it only worked in a tiny subset of cases.

here is pretty much a best case example:

[image: Bokeh Comparison]

the subject is pretty clearly defined from the background (decent shallow depth of field to begin with) and doesn't have long hair.

I could not create a single example that I'd consider worth posting for any person with long hair, which was dissappointing. If you're willing to spend a great amount of time in photoshop tweaking the selection, perhaps you may do better.

Comment: how is this different from selecting the background with lasso/magnetic lasso and Gaussian Blurring it? (just curious)

Comment: it does a better job of aping the look of a real lens. The tool actually has a number of presets for specific lenses (known for their good bokeh), and then lets you tweak. You can simulare a variety of effects like number of aperture blades, etc. as well.

Comment: @JoséNunoFerreira Don't ever use Gaussian Blur to replicate a lens blur. Photoshop has a Lens Blur filter that's much more suited.